# wso2 api manager 1.10 with pre-packaged wso2 Identity server 5.0 - Token regeneration failes

Tags: api, oauth, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I am configuring **WSO2 API Manager 1.10** with Prepackaged Identity server 5.0.

Have followed all steps in https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+the+Identity+Server+5.1.0+as+a+Key+Manager+with+API+Manager+1.10.0.

I am able to do `SSO` with Identity server and **API Manager**. I am able to generated API tokens with Identity server.

When i try to regenerate it fails with error - *Token revoke failed : HTTP error code : 400*

Below are logs from Identity server

```
[2016-06-16 06:26:19,875] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.token.OAuth2TokenEndpoint} -  Error while creating the Carbon OAuth token request
OAuthProblemException{error='invalid_request', description='Missing grant_type parameter value', uri='null', state='null', scope='null', redirectUri='null', responseStatus=0, parameters={}}
        at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.common.exception.OAuthProblemException.error(OAuthProblemException.java:59)
        at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.common.utils.OAuthUtils.handleOAuthProblemException(OAuthUtils.java:167)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.model.CarbonOAuthTokenRequest.initValidator(CarbonOAuthTokenRequest.java:91)
        at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.as.request.OAuthRequest.validate(OAuthRequest.java:60)
        at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.as.request.OAuthRequest.<init>(OAuthRequest.java:52)
        at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.as.request.AbstractOAuthTokenRequest.<init>(AbstractOAuthTokenRequest.java:34)
        at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.as.request.OAuthTokenRequest.<init>(OAuthTokenRequest.java:55)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.model.CarbonOAuthTokenRequest.<init>(CarbonOAuthTokenRequest.java:58)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.token.OAuth2TokenEndpoint.issueAccessToken(OAuth2TokenEndpoint.java:109)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
```

Anyone faced same issues? any help is appreciated.

Comment: How do you regenerate token through UI, or through Token API?

Comment: I am currently testing through UI